# How to define an enum template (C++20)?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, enums, c++20

```
enum ByteOrder :uint16_t
{
    LittleEndian = 0x4949,
    BigEndian = 0x4D4D,
};
template<ByteOrder BO>
enum SF :uint16_t;
template<>
enum SF<LittleEndian>
{
    SF_A = 0x0001;
};
template<>
enum SF<BigEndian>
{
    SF_A = 0x0100;
};
```

Code above is to define an enum template that can adapt itself between 2 different byte orders. However, the compiler says, "An enum template declaration must refer to a previously declared class template member." What does it mean?

Is it possible to define an enum template, but requires a special syntax configuration?

Answer (score 2):

There are no `enum` templates in C++.

You can achieve the desired effect by making the `enum` a member of some class template.

```
template <ByteOrder> class SF_Wrapper;
template <> class SF_Wrapper<LittleEndian> { enum SF ...

template <ByteOrder bo> using SF = SF_Wrapper<bo>::SF;
```